# How to fix jagged texture in raycasting algorithm in Java?

Tags: java, swing, textures, rounding, raycasting

I am trying to implement a raycasting algorithm in Java to render a 3D scene using 2D textures. I followed the tutorial from [here](https://github.com/vinibiavatti1/RayCastingTutorial/wiki/) and modified the code to suit my needs. However, when I run the program, the texture appears jagged and distorted, as shown in the screenshot[image: image 1].

Here is the code that I use for raycasting and drawing the pixel columns:

```
void rayCasting() { double rayAngle = player.viewAng - player.hFOV; for (int i = 0; i < projector.pW; i++, rayAngle += player.incrementAngle) { double dx = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rayAngle)) / precision, dy = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rayAngle)) / precision; double rayX = player.x, rayY = player.y; do { rayX += dx; rayY += dy; } while (map[(int) rayY][(int) rayX] != 1); double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(player.x - rayX, 2) + Math.pow(player.y - rayY, 2)); distance *= Math.cos(Math.toRadians(player.viewAng - rayAngle)); int wallHeight = (int) (projector.hpH / distance); Texture text = textures.get(1); int texturePosX = (int) (text.tW * (rayX + rayY) % text.tW); int[] floor = new int[] { i, projector.hpH + wallHeight, i, projector.pH }; int[] ceiling = new int[] { i, 0, i, projector.hpH - wallHeight }; pixelColumns[i].setVariables(i, wallHeight, texturePosX, floor, ceiling); pixelColumns[i].getTextureStrip(text); } repaint(); }class PixelColumn { int x, y, wallHeight, texturePosX; int[] floor = null, ceiling = null; int[][] strips = null; Color[] colors = null;

    public void setVariables(int x, int wallHeight, int texturePosX, int[] floor, int[] ceiling) {
        this.x = x;
        this.wallHeight = wallHeight;
        this.texturePosX = texturePosX;
        this.floor = floor;
        this.ceiling = ceiling;
    }

    void getTextureStrip(Texture texture) {
        int yInc = wallHeight * 2 / texture.tH;
        y = projector.hpH - wallHeight;
        colors = new Color[texture.tH];
        strips = new int[texture.tH][4];
        for (int i = 0; i < texture.tH; i++, y += yInc) {
            colors[i] = texture.colors[texture.bitmap[i][texturePosX]];
            strips[i] = new int[] { x, y, x, y + yInc };
        }
        int gapFiller = Math.abs((projector.hpH - wallHeight) - y);
        strips[texture.tH - 1][3] += gapFiller;
    }

    void drawPixelColumn(Graphics g2d) {
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.fillRect(ceiling[0], ceiling[1], 1, ceiling[3] - ceiling[1]);
        int n = strips.length;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            g2d.setColor(colors[j]);
            g2d.fillRect(strips[j][0], strips[j][1], 1, strips[j][3] - strips[j][1]);
        }
        g2d.setColor(Color.green);
        g2d.fillRect(floor[0], floor[1], 1, floor[3] - floor[1]);
    }
}
```

in paintComponent I loop over all the PixelColumn objects and pass the Graphics2D object to a PixelColumn's drawPixelColumn method, also I want you to notice gapFiller in drawPixelColumn, before adding it to the final part of the texture strip, I found out there were gaps between the texture strips and floor as shown here, [image: image 2]
so a cheap way to solve this was to add the gap to the final part of the texture strip but that doesn't deny the fact I am doing something wrong, even though before I added textures I was getting smooth walls like this, [image: image 3]
Again any help would be appreciated and I apologize for my poor english.